# Removing corners from 2D Matrix

Tags: python, c++, r, arrays, matrix

I wan't to highlight the corners of a 2D Matrix in an effizient way so i can remove them later.
Im doing this in C++ but advice in any language is welcomed.

```py
Given 2D Matrix:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


Desired 2D Matrix:
[[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7],
 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
 [7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]

My code:

from pprint import pprint

m = [[0 for i in range(11)] for j in range(11)]
delta = int(len(m)/2)
toRemove = 7
m[delta][delta] = toRemove


b = 0

for counter in range(delta):
    up = m[counter]
    low = m[-counter - 1]
    for innerCounter in range(delta - counter):
        up[innerCounter] = toRemove
        up[-innerCounter - 1] = toRemove
        low[innerCounter] = toRemove
        low[-innerCounter - 1] = toRemove
    m[counter] = up
    m[-counter - 1] = low 

pprint(m)
```

I don't know if this is the most effizient way and how hard this is to implement in C++. This is just what I came up with in a few minutes.

Comment: If you've already written code and need help with it, the general procedure is to show the code you've written.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a 2D binary array with 1's forming a "diamond" shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855924/how-to-create-a-2d-binary-array-with-1s-forming-a-diamond-shape)

Comment: @anurag hmmm kinda hard recreating this and i want to make highlight everything outside of the diamond

Comment: @paddy ill go and include my code

Comment: @NicoM do you want the answer in python or C++?

Comment: One way to think about it is that if the Manhattan distance from the center to any element is in the range `[1,  width / 2]` then the cell is a zero.

Comment: @anurag c++ is prefered but any solution is welcomed

Comment: @paddy trying to implement something like this right now. Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This python code, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56856324/14739759), will produce the requisite result:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

N = a.shape[0]
H = abs(np.arange(1-N,N+1,2))//2
#print(H)
V = H[0] - H[:,None]
diamond = (H>V)*7
result = np.add(a, diamond)

print(result)
```

```bash
[[7 7 7 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 7]
 [7 7 7 7 0 0 0 7 7 7 7]
 [7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7]
 [7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7]
 [7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7]
 [0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0]
 [7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7]
 [7 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 7]
 [7 7 7 0 0 0 0 0 7 7 7]
 [7 7 7 7 0 0 0 7 7 7 7]
 [7 7 7 7 7 0 7 7 7 7 7]]
```